# WP7 Facebook SDK - Connecting the user automatically

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm currently writing a facebook app for windows phone, and there is something I just didn't find how to do.

Since display=touch currently doesn't work on windows phone, I am forced to use display=popup to get a token and the user's agreement for my app.
This popup mode really isn't fit for mobile apps, so I would like the user to be able to check a box saying "I would like the app to remember my login and password and connect me automatically".

However, when I have the user's login and password, I don't know how to use the OAuth API to effectively login the user without him having to click anything. Is there a way to do that ? Or do I have to wait for the user to choose "Remember me" on the Facebook login page ?

I hope that was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn't have a (public) API for taking a users email address and password and returning an access token.  The closest thing you can do is customize the HTML that gets returned with JavaScript.  I have an example of this on my [github](https://github.com/offbysome/Facebook-WP7-Login-Button).

Comment: Okay that's what I thought...
Thanks a lot for confirming that so quickly :)